# Google Cloud Platform and WebUSB API

Tags: .net, security, google-cloud-platform, webusb

I am in the process of converting a Windows .NET desktop application (running on hundreds of PCs)  that sends and receives USB data to an Azure Service. I am investigating migrating the current architecture from Azure to Google Cloud Platform. In my preliminary brainstorming, I was also thinking about eliminating the desktop applications. Having a web based application replace the desktop application is intriguing to me. I just came across WebUSB API. Would this be an appropriate design decision? Can WebUSB be used with Google Cloud Platform? Is the security built into the WebUSB API designed to be strong enough for a rigorous production environment that includes personal data?

Comment: It's only a draft standard that might change. Also consider whether this is enough for your usecase: https://caniuse.com/webusb

Answer (score 2):

The choice of client and server platform are mostly unrelated. You can use WebUSB with a service running on Azure, GCP, AWS, or a server in your closet. Anything which can serve a website can serve a website that uses WebUSB.

The question of whether you can use WebUSB mostly comes down to the kind of USB device that you are collecting data from. WebUSB is most useful for "vendor specific" devices, where the operating system doesn't provide the driver support for the device and instead the application acts as the driver. If your existing application uses the WinUSB library (or its .NET equivalent) then it should work with WebUSB. If your device is a serial or HID device then you might want to look into the WebHID or Web Serial APIs instead. https://web.dev/devices-introduction/ is a good introduction to how to think about accessing hardware peripherals from the web.

WebUSB is designed to protect user data. The permission model requires the user to select the device they want to share access to with the website. The API is also only available on HTTPS sites so that the data the site gets access to can only be sent over an encrypted link back to the server.